# removing elements of a list until given index without using a loop

Tags: python, list

Just a small question im trying to tackle but having an issue with.
When I do this step by step in the python shell like so:

```
lista=[2,4,5,1,2,7,8,12,3,4,0,27,4,9]

list=list.sort()
l = list.index(5)
listfinal= list[l::]
print(listfinal)
```

it works, so I don't get with it gives me a NonType error on *list[**list.index(x)**::]* in my function beneath:

```
def remove_menores(list,x):
    list=list.sort()
    listfinal= list[list.index(x)::]
    print(listfinal)
```

anybody able to tell me why this is?

Comment: Please don't call variables `list`. As well as being a cause of all sorts of different behaviour, your actual intent is not so clear anymore

Comment: @roganjosh where did i do that?

Comment: `list=list.sort()`

Comment: @roganjosh ohh thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`list.sort()` returns `None`, thus, it is not necessary to store its returned value. Instead, try this:

```
def remove_menores(list,x):
  list.sort()
  listfinal= list[list.index(x)::]
  print(listfinal)
```

Comment: `list.sort`  mutates the external `lista` - a potentially bad side effect - functions shouldn't have uncessary side effects  `listfinal= sorted(lst)[lst.index(x)::]` does the job without sorting the external `lista`